how to construct a std::map of topic_name(std::string) as key and ros2 msg class(ptr) as value?
i need a std::map with topic_name as key and some-different-types of msgdata(or msgdata prt) as value in ros2, like

// here is the question, how to declare the std::map, i.e. ref_maps;
std::map<std::string, pkg::msg::SomeVariantType> map_msg;
std::map<std::string, pkg::msg::SomeVariantType::SharedPtr> map_ptr;


// type one 
pkg::msg::TypeOne msg1;
pkg::msg::TypeOne::SharedPtr ptr1; 
std::string topic_name1 = "t1"

// type two
pkg::msg::TypeTwo msg2;
pkg::msg::TypeTwo::SharedPtr ptr2; 
std::string topic_name2 = "t2"

map_msg[t1] = msg1;
map_msg[t2] = msg2;

map_ptr[t1] = ptr1;
map_ptr[t2] = ptr2;


is this possible or any other method to implemante similiar result?
are different ros2 msgTypes( and ::SharedPtr) inheret from some base class so that i can declare maps like:
std::map<std::string, MsgTypeBase> map_msg;
std::map<std::string, PtrTypeBase> map_ptr;

